# What is Token Based Authentication, How to access REST API GET request using it? NETSUITE API

Tags: python, curl, postman

I cannot figure out that how can I get a GET request and authorize them using token-based authorization where I have only consumer and token keys with their secrets.

Answer (score 0):

Search for token based authentication for restlets.
e.g.
[Looking for example Python code for Netsuite API using OAuth?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33174172/looking-for-example-python-code-for-netsuite-api-using-oauth)

The concept remains the same - you need to add the authentication data to the header when you make the GET request.